# Unable to access REST API of a SPRING BOOT Application which is running in my computer, from another computer in same network

Tags: rest, tomcat, spring-boot, lan

I have created some rest APIs in a spring boot application. By running "ipconfig" command in cmd i got my ip and able to access the API from my computer using below URL :`http://192.168.0.4:8080/topics`.

But when I try accessing it from another computer's browser ,its not happening. Browser is taking a long time and after that its displaying "took too long to respond". FYI both the computers connected to same wifi. We are using internet provided by local internet provider at my home. Servlet container is the embedded Tomcat server provided by Spring boot application.

please suggest how can my API be accessed by other computers in same network.
Let me know if you need any more information.

I have checked my local computer's firewall log file while hitting this URL. I am getting below logs :

```
2017-10-21 22:33:54 DROP TCP 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.4 57405 8080 60 S 
2319032371 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2017-10-21 22:33:54 DROP TCP 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.4 57406 8080 60 S 
2870949788 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2017-10-21 22:33:54 DROP TCP 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.4 57407 8080 60 S 
2073270052 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
```

Comment: Do you have a local firewall running on your computer?

Comment: Firewall is on, but I have also added an inbound port rule on this port 8080 to allow all incoming request on this port

Comment: Are those computers in the same domain? Or you may need to enable CORS in your application.

Comment: it was a firewall issue.. all the requests were getting dropped.. nothing to do with application... issue is resolved now..thnks

Comment: @smrutiranjan please share the solution here, how did you resolve the issue, I am facing the same issue here

Comment: @KhalidHabib For me it was  a network security issue  with firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found out it was caused by firewall & wi-fi network properties.

- In my case, I wanted to connect to a Spring Boot app from another computer, same network.
- It was working for an older version of Spring Boot + Java (2.1.7 & 1.8), but not working for newer version (Spring Boot 2.4.1 + Java 15).
- The issue was that the newer Java version was allowed only on private network in the firewall inbound rules and my wi-fi was set to public.
- (The older Java version was allowed on public network, that's why it was working).

So, the fix for my issue was to change the Wi-Fi network from Public to Private. Be careful, by doing this, other things may break.

Answer (score -1):

Add a new rule in your windows firewall and it will work

Comment: This answer could be made better by providing an example of the rule you are suggesting.  Please see: [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)